# Merge objects while preserving unique attributes

Tags: c#, merge

I am working on a C# project that takes lists of hundreds of objects of a custom class, and merges them together into a new list.  There may be some cases where a single real-world item is represented several times in the list, but with different attributes.  I am looking for an efficient way to merge these two lists together in such a way that any time a duplicate is found on my search key property, the other properties are merged together (either by overwriting the attributes of one of the objects or by creating a new object with the merged attributes) instead of deleting the second instance.

Here is an example of what I want to do:
Objects of class Dog with elements (ID, Owner, Breed, Colour). The Dog Rover is owned by both Sharon and Paul.  I want my merged list to include the text “Sharon/Paul” as the new attribute for the “Owner” variable.

**Original lists:**

List A:

1.Rover (23, Sharon, Labrador, Black)

2.Spot (40, Paul, Retriever, Golden)

List B:

1. Rover (23, Paul, Labrador, Black)

**Merged list:**

1. Rover (23, Sharon/ Paul, Labrador, Black)
2. Spot (40, Paul, Retriever, Golden)

I have been able to join the lists to create:
1.  Rover (23, Sharon, Labrador, Black)
2.  Rover (23, Paul, Labrador, Black)
3.  Spot (40, Paul, Retriever, Golden)
Or run .Unique on the lists to create:
1.  Rover (23, Sharon, Labrador, Black)
2.  Spot (40, Paul, Retriever, Golden)

But neither of those give me all of the information I need in the smallest list possible.

Comment: Share your code that you wrote to solve the above problem

Comment: Is there a common base class? Is it a list of objects or a list of key/value pairs or a map or dictionary of some sort?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is a full outer join to get all the dogs, and then merge the matching dogs. A full outer join is done in LINQ by doing a left outer join and then a right anti semi join and then using `Union` to combine them.

I assumed each dog ID will appear at most once in each list and that `Breed` and `Colour` would be identical, if not you can merge them like `Owner`.

```
var leftDogs = from da in dogsA
               join db in dogsB on da.ID equals db.ID into dbj
               from db in dbj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new Dog {
                   ID = da.ID,
                   Owner = (db == null ? da.Owner : $"{da.Owner}/{db.Owner}"),
                   Breed = da.Breed,
                   Colour = da.Colour
               };

var rightDogs = from db in dogsB
                where !dogsA.Any(da => da.ID == db.ID)
                select db;

var ans = leftDogs.Union(rightDogs);
```

If there is a possibility of duplicate entries in each list for multiple owner dogs, you can reduce the first list then reduce the combination:

```
public static IEnumerable<Dog> MergeDupDogs(IEnumerable<Dog> dogsA, IEnumerable<Dog> dogsB) {
    var dogsAReduced = dogsA.Aggregate(new Dictionary<int, Dog>(), (acc, da) => {
        if (!acc.ContainsKey(da.ID))
            acc.Add(da.ID, da);
        else
            acc[da.ID] = new Dog { ID = da.ID, Owner = $"{acc[da.ID].Owner}/{da.Owner}", Breed = da.Breed, Colour = da.Colour };
        return acc;
    });

    return dogsB.Aggregate(dogsAReduced, (acc, db) => {
        if (!acc.ContainsKey(db.ID))
            acc.Add(db.ID, db);
        else
            acc[db.ID] = new Dog { ID = db.ID, Owner = $"{acc[db.ID].Owner}/{db.Owner}", Breed = db.Breed, Colour = db.Colour };
        return acc;
    }).Select(e => e.Value);
}
```

Comment: What if there are more then 2 owners?

Comment: As stated in the answer, I assume each dog ID appears at most once in each list. The original question doesn't discuss the possibility of more than two owners.

Comment: @SledgeHammer I added an option to reduce the lists together.

Comment: I modified the duplicate version to use a `Dictionary` for much better efficiency.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage for the fast answers and great solutions.  I tried out both of your options and they both worked on my project. (And thank you SledgeHammer for inspiring the option to reduce the lists together).

Comment: I appreciate it, but I have to give credit to @Enigmativity for his answer using `concat` to make it one list with no special cases.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have lists defined like this:

```
var listA = new []
{
    new Dog() { ID  = 23, Owner = "Sharon", Breed = "Labrador", Colour = "Black" },
    new Dog() { ID  = 40, Owner = "Paul", Breed = "Retriever", Colour = "Golden" },
};

var listB = new []
{
    new Dog() { ID  = 23, Owner = "Paul", Breed = "Labrador", Colour = "Black" },
};
```

The interesting thing from your data is that the `Dog` records are not normalized - you have the same `ID` with different property data, i.e. the `Owner` can be different. I think it's then important to also make sure that the final query also ensures that multiple values in the `Breed` and `Colour` properties are also handled.

The query you need is:

```
var query =
    from dog in listA.Concat(listB)
    orderby dog.ID
    group dog by dog.ID into gdogs
    select new Dog()
    {
        ID = gdogs.Key,
        Owner = String.Join("/", gdogs.Select(x => x.Owner).Distinct()),
        Breed = String.Join("/", gdogs.Select(x => x.Breed).Distinct()),
        Colour = String.Join("/", gdogs.Select(x => x.Colour).Distinct()),
    };
```

If you have multiple lists you just simply keep calling `.Concat` to join them together.

The result you get from this query is:

[image: query]

Comment: Nice use of `Concat` / `group` `by`!